# Why it is called Marshalling?

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, marshalling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the concept of Marshalling called as such?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942362/why-is-the-concept-of-marshalling-called-as-such)

Why the conversion between two types is called Marshalling! What is the meaning behind `Marshal`, why we don't just use the word `convert`, is there any difference. Please try to keep a simple english as possible as you can.

Comment: Strange that this "duplicate" question was asked almost exactly 1 year later.

Comment: I always figured it was an homage to Marshall McCluhan. He has the best theories of new media.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Usually the word "marshalling" is used when you're crossing some sort of boundary. Three obvious use cases:

- Remoting: the RPC data is marshalled to a separate machine (usually)
- AppDomains: an object crossing an AppDomain boundary needs to be marshalled (or it may be [marshalled by reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx))
- Cross-thread calls: if you use `Control.Invoke` or something similar, that's called *marshalling* the delegate call to a different thread; so in this case the thread is the boundary

Plain conversions with no such boundaries involved *are* called just conversions.

For the reasoning behind using the word "marshal" here, see [Etienne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168717/why-it-is-called-marshalling/6168740#6168740).

Comment: I think this answers _when_, not _why_

Comment: @Henk: Sort of - I think it works well in conjunction with Etienne's answer. Will edit to point that out.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but on #2, when you said "AppDomains: an obvious crossing", do you mean "an obvious process, crossing" or "an obvious" like "an obvious data crossing"? I know this is a little unrelated but was wondering what you actually meant there. Because I thought "obvious" was adjective.

Comment: @Joan: It was a typo for "object". Oops :)

Comment: Thanks man, didn't mean to nitpick as I am not good at English like you :O

Comment: @Jon Skeet,
I never did marshaling before. I'd like to know more about this technique. 
Can I marshal an object which is inside one of my application and after serialization can I send it to another application through tcp or any other means?
If I could do that, how could marshaling able to manage pointers which might be defined in the object? From your answer, it seems the objects can be send to remote PCs and multiple app domains. could you please explain?

Comment: @BeediKumaraN: Not in comments, really - I suggest you ask a *specific* question about something *precise* that you're trying to achieve... whereupon someone with more experience of marshalling can answer...

Answer (score 46):

Because it's not the same thing.

From Wikipedia:

> In computer science, marshalling (sometimes spelled marshaling, similar to serialization) is the process of transforming the memory representation of an object to a data format suitable for storage or transmission. It is typically used when data must be moved between different parts of a computer program or from one program to another.

Comment: Damn, I'm up against Jon Skeet!

Comment: In this case it feels like a cooperative task - our answers complement each other pretty well.

Answer (score 42):

The word Marshal comes from Millitary terms.  Such as to Marshal ones troops and move them somewhere else.  From the dictionary:

> to arrange in proper order; set out in an orderly manner; arrange clearly:
>
> - to marshal facts; to marshal one's arguments.
> - to array, as for battle.
> - to usher or lead ceremoniously: Their host marshaled them into the room.

Comment: this one actually answers the question

Comment: Yes, the others are tautologies.

Comment: Glad someone actually answered the question and not give a definition of what Marshalling is. Surprisingly the rest of the internet is like the other answers here, just wants to explain what I already know, and not just answer the simple etymology of the word that I was curious of.

Answer (score 7):

Conversion between two types isn't called marshaling.

Marshaling is moving an object between memory spaces, e.g. different processes, different computers, or different COM apartments.  Often serialization is required, to create a portable encoding that doesn't use pointers that are meaningless in the other memory space, and the type changes during serialization, but type conversion and marshaling are orthogonal concepts.  Especially, marshalling simple types such as `int` and `double` (or structures of those) can be done with a simple copy and no conversion.

Comment: marshal is move and rearrange. This doesn't necessarily mean to different memory spaces. I can martial within the same process on the same heap so that a different part of my code in a different language can use it.

Comment: So, in a c# controller, if you take an object and serialize it into JSON, then return that JSON to the javascript... have you marshalled the Object?

Answer (score 5):

For a linguistic insight, a [marshalling yard](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/marshalling+yard) is where a railway company re-arranges their trains.